# Django rest framework + Scrapy [twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable]. (Flutter + Dart)

Tags: django, flutter, dart, django-rest-framework, scrapy

I am working on a project that mixes a Django API with Scrapy, the idea is to run the API from my cell phone, said API will run the spider and then return all the information that I will get on my cell phone. When I do the search for the first time on the cellphone, everything works perfectly, but when I try to do another search, I get "twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable"

Here's my API

```
class Prueba(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    dato = request.data['dato']
    if dato:
        imprimir = self.execute(dato)
        res = json.dumps([o.dump() for o in imprimir], indent=3)
        return HttpResponse(res, content_type='application/json', status = status.HTTP_200_OK)  
    else:
        return HttpResponse("NO", content_type='application/json')


def execute(self, peticion):

    url = ['https://listado.mercadolibre.com.co/'+peticion]
    url2 = ['https://www.olx.com.co/items/q-'+peticion]
            
    process = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'})
    process.crawl(ProductoSpider, start_urls=url)
    process.crawl(ProductoSpiderDos, start_urls=url2)
    process.start()
    
    return outputResponse #global variable in my spider
```

Here's one of my spiders, I know it's a bit weird, but it's because I've been testing a few things.

```
class ProductoSpiderDos(CrawlSpider):
name = 'olx'

item_count = 0
allowed_domain = ['www.olx.com.co']

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)


#//button[@data-aut-id="btnLoadMore"]
#//div[@class="JbJAl"]
rules = {

    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = (), restrict_xpaths = ('//button[@data-aut-id="btnLoadMore"]'))),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = (), restrict_xpaths = ('//li[@data-aut-id="itemBox"]/a')),
                        callback = "parse_item", follow = False),
}

def parse_item(self, response):
    global outputResponse

    lista = {}
    
    agg = Producto()

    agg.titulo = response.xpath('//h1[@class="_3rJ6e"]/text()').extract_first()
    agg.urlimg = response.xpath('//img[@data-aut-id="defaultImg"]/@src').extract_first()
    p = response.xpath('//span[@data-aut-id="itemPrice"]/text()').extract_first()
    ch = ".$ "
    for x in range(len(ch)):
        p = p.replace(ch[x],"")
    agg.precio = p
    agg.url = response.request.url

    lista['url'] = response.request.url
    
    outputResponse.append(agg)
    self.item_count += 1
    if self.item_count > 3:
        raise CloseSpider('item_exceeded')
        
    yield lista
```

I don't know if this helps, but here is a part of my mobile app's code (Flutter + Dart)

When I call the API

```
void buscar(BuildContext context) async {
  List<Producto> ulist = [];
  if (buscarController.text.isNotEmpty) {
    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.3:8000/api/experimento"),
      body: {'dato': buscarController.text});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var urjson = json.decode(response.body);

      for (var jsondata in urjson) {
        ulist.add(Producto.fromJson(jsondata));
      }
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Ha ocurrido un problema")));
    }
  }
  setState(() {
    productos = ulist;
  });
}
```

As a test, I'm only using two of the data I receive from the API

```
return Card(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(productos[index].titulo.toString()),
                Text(productos[index].precio.toString())
              ],
            ),
          );
```

And here's a picture so that you can understand what I want to do. this is how it looks like when I use it for the first time

[image: Screenshot]